# pandas Series.min() returns nothing when series contains a missing value

Tags: pandas

Pandas newbie here. I have a series of dtype:object (contains strings). I've noticed that Series.max() can find the alphabetical max even if the series contains a missing value. But Series.min() does not work if the series contains no missing values. See illustration below.

Is there a way I can get the alphabetical minimum value in the series even if the series contains some missing values?

P.S. I'm using python 2.7.3, pandas 0.11.0.

```
import pandas as pd

# s1 contains no missing items
s1 = pd.Series(['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta'])

#s2 contains one missing item
s2 = pd.Series(['alpha', '', 'charlie', 'delta'])

print 's1 min: %s' % s1.min()
print 's1 max: %s' % s1.max()
print 's2 min: %s' % s2.min()
print 's2 max: %s' % s2.max()


##output:
##s1 min: alpha
##s1 max: delta
##s2 min: 
##s2 max: delta
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because `''` is the smallest value:

```
In [11]: '' < 'a'
Out[11]: True

In [12]: s2.min() == ''
Out[12]: True
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes total sense now as to why it's happening.

Answer (score 3):

You could select all values other than the empty string before taking the `min`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s2 = pd.Series(['alpha', '', 'charlie', 'delta'])
>>> s2[s2 != ''].min()
'alpha'
```

Comment: interestingly the docstring says it should return a float (so it returns inf if you have NaN instead of '') :s

Comment: @AndyHayden: Shouldn't `pd.Series(['alpha', np.nan, 'charlie', 'delta']).min()` skip the `np.nan` value since `skipna=True` by default?

Comment: yes/probably (it doesn't though) :( think this is unsupported behaviour, will put together a github issue

Comment: Here is the reason. Is this a numpy bug? ``np.array(['alpha', np.inf, 'charlie', 'delta'],dtype=object).min()`` evaluates to ``inf``, while ``max`` evaluates to ``'delta'``, very curious, prob just put in a special case for ``object`` dtypes for ``min/max`` to take care of this

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of this technique.

Comment: @Jeff: In NumPy the standard way to ignore NaNs when taking a min is to use `np.nanmin`, but `np.nanmin(np.array(['alpha', 'bravo', np.nan, 'delta'], dtype='object'))` evaluates to `np.nan`. `np.nanmin` does not seem to behave according to [its documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html) when the dtype is `object`.

Comment: pandas uses the above technique as faster than ``np.nanmin`` (this actually only happens if bottleneck is not installed; thats much faster); and ``nans`` are already masked. but I see what you are saying, the docs don't really specify what happens with ``dtype=object``, but oddly they work for ``max``

Comment: @unutbu I think it's ambiguously (un?)supported "Array containing *numbers* whose minimum is desired..." :s

Comment: @AndyHayden: That's true; I missed that. However, `np.nanmin(np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 3], dtype='object'))` also evaluates to `nan`, which *really* contradicts the documentation.

Comment: @Jeff: In Python2, any float is less than any string, since the string `'float'` comes before `'string'` alphabetically. (I'm not making this up.) So `np.array(['alpha', np.inf, 'charlie', 'delta'],dtype=object).min()` evaluates to `inf` simply because `inf` is a float and all the other items are strings. This wart was corrected in Python3, where strings and floats were made incomparable. So NumPy developers would probably say it is not a bug, it is just a Python2 wart.

Comment: that is very odd. in any event I think Andy is going to open an issue in regards to this

Comment: Correction: That floats always compare less than strings is a [CPython implementation detail](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons): "Objects of different types except numbers are
ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper
comparison are ordered by their address."

Comment: posted both a numpy and pandas issue https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3508, let me know if I missed anything

Comment: You can use `dataframe.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])` to keep only numeric columns